# AJAX and Back button (Cant get JQUERY history working)

Tags: jquery, browser-history

I am busy with making a advertisement website, on the categorie pages the screen is adjusable by the user (see http://www.huurhulp.nl/verhuur/vakantie-en-recreatie/), for example the next page wil call a AJAX request and loads the new advertisements. I know that the back button is not working with AJAX, for example if i click on an advertesiment and want to ga back to the overview (page 3) so i tried severall JQUERY History examples but i can't get them working. Is JQUERY History the only option, am i doing something wrong and does anybody got a good example?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [**Ben Alman's Back Button and Query**](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) plugin.

This allows you to easily push 'state' into the browsers url. eg `$.bbq.pushState("page", "2")` adds `#page=2` to the browsers url.

```
http://www.huurhulp.nl/verhuur/vakantie-en-recreatie/#page=2
```

You then hook up an event handler that fires whenever the hash changes and handle your ajax navigation in there. eg

```
$(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
    var category = $.bbq.getState("category");
    // do your ajax stuff here....
});
```

The only other thing left to do for back button support is to trigger the hashchange event whenever the page is first loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
});
```